# shell_exec without waiting for the output

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Asynchronous shell exec in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222414/asynchronous-shell-exec-in-php)
>   [Is there a way to use shell_exec without waiting for the command to complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019867/is-there-a-way-to-use-shell-exec-without-waiting-for-the-command-to-complete)

I want to run a quite slow / complex program which takes at least 10 minutes to complete. I want to call this via shell_exec or something similar, but I dont want the php script to wait for the completion of this program.

is thing something I can do? and if so how can I do that?

Comment: You can use Tasks https://github.com/jamm/Tasks module - special for delayed execution without waiting and without using `shell_exec`. Or you can read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019867/php-shell-execute-without-waiting-for-a-return/1019904#1019904 :)

Comment: I quite didnt understand this one

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process

Comment: hi there - many thanks dear nivanka - thank you for this thread. it is very helpful. You have helped me alot.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This has been answered before at [Asynchronous shell exec in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222414/asynchronous-shell-exec-in-php)

Briefly:

```
shell_exec( $your_command . "> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &" );
```