# Send HTTP request from PHP without waiting for response?

Tags: php, http, curl, server-side, web-analytics

I want to have an HTTP GET request sent from PHP. Example:

```
http://tracker.example.com?product_number=5230&price=123.52
```

The idea is to do server-side web-analytics: Instead of sending tracking
information from JavaScript to a server, the server sends tracking
information directly to another server.

Requirements:

- The request should take as little time as possible, in order to not
  noticeably delay processing of the PHP page.
- The response from the `tracker.example.com` does not need to be
  checked. As examples, some possible responses from
  `tracker.example.com`:

  - *200:* That's fine, but no need to check that.
  - *404:* Bad luck, but - again - no need to check that.
  - *301:* Although a redirect would be appropriate, it would delay
    processing of the PHP page, so don't do that.

  In short: *All* responses can be discarded.

Ideas for solutions:

- In a now deleted answer, someone suggested calling command line
  [curl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) from PHP in a shell process. This seems like a good idea,
  only that I don't know if forking a lot of shell processes under
  heavy load is a wise thing to do.
- I found [php-ga](http://code.google.com/p/php-ga/), a package for doing server-side Google
  Analytics from PHP. On the project's page, it is
  mentioned: *"Can be configured to [...] use non-blocking requests."*
  So far I haven't found the time to investigate what method php-ga
  uses internally, but this method could be it!

In a nutshell: What is the best solution to do generic server-side
tracking/analytics from PHP.

Comment: madflow: Because in tracking should not slow down page load time. If the tracker fails, then bad luck - but no need to check that every time.

Comment: @Will: Note that I am asking for a *method*, and not necessarily for a package. For example, the method that [php-ga](http://code.google.com/p/php-ga/) uses for doing non-blocking requests could be of interest also for tracking solutions that are - like in my case - *not* based on Google Analytics.

Comment: @Will: There was one answer that could be definite, but that requires more discussion concerning possible performance issues. Unfortunately it has been deleted. The idea was calling command line `curl` from PHP. If there was a link, I believe it can be removed. `curl` is part of the standard UNIX web server tool chain (`curllib` is accessible from PHP, by the way). In addition, once I find the time, I would like to look into *php-ga* and investigate the *method* that is uses for non-blocking requests. But maybe someone on Stack Overflow knows this off the top of his head?

Comment: @Will: Then the question would become too specific, already related to one specific way to send a request to the tracker. Only if absolutely necessary, I want fork a shell process and run `curl` in it. But if I do so, then the method in the linked question could be *one part* of the solution.

Comment: Alright.  Please [edit] the question to add all the relevant details from your comments.  Hopefully we won't get anymore link-only answers.

Comment: @Khez If you have found a solution in the meantime, it would be great if you could post it!

Comment: @feklee wasn't this question closed? Sure, there's a couple of techniques for low latency "pinging" of pages, I'll make a response by the end of the day.

Comment: @Khez: It was reopened. :-)

Comment: @feklee Sorry for the long wait, made an answer (not very proud of the content). If you want I might edit and offer a little bit more information (maybe some code examples). I started Friday night to make an answer but ended up giving way to much information (in a not very structured fashion).

Comment: Possibly useful: https://segment.io/blog/how-to-make-async-requests-in-php/ and [Asynchronous PHP calls?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/124462)/ (maybe the second one is even a duplicate? will look more later.)

Comment: @JeremyBanks The segment.io article looks very interesting - thanks! Note that I don't need a response, though.

Comment: @Khez Thanks. Now it took me long to reply, sorry about that. I highly appreciate your answer. Perhaps one day I will find the time to look into *php-ga* and how it does non blocking tracking requests.

Comment: it uses [stream_set_blocking](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-blocking.php), but that affects reading and writing to the stream not "http-ping-ing"

Comment: @Khez: Still interesting. I didn't know about `stream_set_blocking‌​`. Perhaps you add it to your answer?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Unfortunately PHP by definition is **blocking**. While this holds true for the majority of functions and operations you will normally be handling, the current scenario is different.

The process which I like to call [HTTP-Ping](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/http-ping/), requires that you only *touch* a specific URI, forcing the specific server to boot-strap it's internal logic. Some functions allow you to achieve something very similar to this *HTTP-ping*, by not waiting for a response.

Take note that the process of *pinging* an url, is a two step process:

1. Resolve the DNS
2. Making the request

While making the request should be rather fast once the DNS is resolved and the connection is made, there aren't many ways of making the DNS resolve faster.

Some ways of doing an http-ping are:

1. [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php), by setting CONNECTION_TIMEOUT to a low value
2. [fsockopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) by closing immediately after writing
3. [stream_socket_client](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php) (same as fsockopen) and also adding `STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT`

While both `cURL` and `fsockopen` are both blocking while the DNS is being resolved. I have noticed that *fsockopen* is significantly faster, even in worst case scenarios.

`stream_socket_client` on the other hand should fix the problem regarding DNS resolving and should be the optimal solution in this scenario, but I have not managed to get it to work.

One final solution is to start another thread/process that does this for you. Making a system call for this should work, but also [forking](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) the current process should do that also. Unfortunately both are not really safe in applications where you can't control the environment on which PHP is running.

System calls are more often than not blocked and pcntl is not enabled by default.

Comment: Actually, I could avoid the DNS look up by specifying an IP. It just didn't occur to me yet.

Comment: @feklee wanted to mention it in the post, but near the end I was already wondering what access rights you have on the server. Careful for DNS changes though!

Comment: I don't fully understand what access rights have to do with specifying an IP (other than that I could specify it also in `/etc/hosts`), but I do have full access rights (root). In any case, a generic answer obviously suites Stack Overflow best.

Comment: Khez I have to say that is a beautiful solution. It may even have potential for very basic asynchrony in php without a plugin

Comment: @DaMaxContent well, async is already part of the hack spec and I wouldn't be surprised if PHP 7.x will pickup on it... but I'm glad you found the solution "beautiful" :D

Comment: Hi @Khez, mind to share which solution work great nowadays without using any third party plugins?

Answer (score 24):

I would call tracker.example.com this way:

```
get_headers('http://tracker.example.com?product_number=5230&price=123.52');
```

and in the tracker script:

```
ob_end_clean();
ignore_user_abort(true);
ob_start();
header("Connection: close");
header("Content-Length: " . ob_get_length());
ob_end_flush();
flush();

// from here the response has been sent. you can now wait as long as you want and do some tracking stuff 

sleep(5); //wait 5 seconds
do_some_stuff();
exit;
```

Comment: `ignore_user_abort()` needs a value (true), otherwise it will only return its current value.

Comment: it works fine on my local wamp server, but not on my server. i think my server needs configuration

Answer (score 17):

I implemented function for fast GET request to url without waiting for response:

```
function fast_request($url)
{
    $parts=parse_url($url);
    $fp = fsockopen($parts['host'],isset($parts['port'])?$parts['port']:80,$errno, $errstr, 30);
    $out = "GET ".$parts['path']." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out.= "Host: ".$parts['host']."\r\n";
    $out.= "Content-Length: 0"."\r\n";
    $out.= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

    fwrite($fp, $out);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: if you want to add query parameters to your request change the "GET" line to this:

`$out = "GET ".$parts['path'] . "?" . $parts['query'] . " HTTP/1.1\r\n";`

Comment: Simple and elegant solution. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

We were using `fsockopen` and `fwrite` combo, then it up and stopped working one day. Or it was kind of intermittent. After a little research and testing, and if you have fopen wrappers enabled, I ended up using `file_get_contents` and `stream_context_create` functions with a timeout that is set to 100th of second. The timeout parameter can receive floating values (https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php). I wrapped it in a try...catch block so it would fail silently. It works beautifully for our purposes. You can do logging stuff in the catch if needed. The timeout is the key if you don't want the function to block runtime.

```
function fetchWithoutResponseURL( $url )
{

    $context = stream_context_create([
        "http" => [
            "method"=>"GET",
            "timeout" => .01
            ]
        ]
    );

    try {
        file_get_contents($url, 0, $context);
    }catch( Exception $e ){
        // Fail silently
    }
}
```

Comment: If SSL handshake and other connection preparation steps are not completed in 10ms this would fail to initiate a connection. Actually, all solutions that depends on connection timeout would fail if you are targeting a piece of code in the target script and it fails to run in this limited time span. To make sure the target script runs fully, you have to wait until the connection closes.

Answer (score 4):

For those of you working with wordrpess as a backend - 
it is as simple as:

`wp_remote_get( $url, array(blocking=>false) );`

Comment: Thanks, that's a really good tip, and exactly what I was looking for! Submitting an email for sending via Autopilot via CURL was taking anywhere from 2 to 12 seconds, but using this method got the time down to around 2 seconds consistently. Of course, this means that we can't see the results of the POST request – but I was never doing anything with the response from Autopilot anyway, so that doesn't matter in my case.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `shell_exec`, and command line curl.

For an example, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019867/is-there-a-way-to-use-shell-exec-without-waiting-for-the-command-to-complete)

Comment: This looks like a decent solution. Only I wonder whether it could be problematic to spawn lots of shell processes when many users are accessing the page.

Comment: Can you flesh this answer out a bit? (see edits made to question)

Answer (score 3):

Came here whilst researching a similar problem. If you have a database connection handy, one other possibility is to quickly stuff the request details into a table, and then have a seperate cron-based process that periodically scans that table for new records to process, and makes the tracking request, freeing up your web application from having to make the HTTP request itself.

Comment: Actually, in the app in question there is something like that. It's not Cron based, however (I try to avoid Cron). It's a daemon that downloads from URLs read from a database, in an infinite loop. For the given use case, though, utilizing that daemon and the associated database feels like overkill.

Answer (score -1):

You can actually do this using `CURL` directly.

I have both implemented it using a very short timeout (`CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS`) and/or using `curl_multi_exec`.

Be advised: eventually i quit this method because not every request was correctly made. This could have been caused by my own server though i haven't been able to rule out the option of curl failing.

Comment: Isn't it likely that the requests failed because in fact a connection has to be established before sending the request? AFAICS, for the problem at hand, it is unwise to set CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS to an extremely low value.

Answer (score -1):

I needed to do something similar, just ping a url and discard all responses. I used the proc_open command which lets you end the process right away using proc_close. I'm assuming you have lynx installed on your server:

```
<?php    
function ping($url) {
      $proc = proc_open("lynx $url",[],$pipes);
      proc_close($proc);
    }
?>
```

Comment: It waits until the command is fully executed

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en" 
  )
);

 $context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents('http://tracker.example.com?product_number=5230&price=123.52', false, $context);
?>
```

Comment: Perhaps offer an explanation for how your code works and why it fulfills the needs of the questioner?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will do the whole request and wait for a response before proceeding won't it ?