# Wordpress Plugin Log Request Information

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to write a plugin which logs in a file information about each request made by users. I hooked it to the init action, but i don't know how to get the response status for the request. All the other information like ip, user-agent is available on the $_SERVER variable, but this one is not. Any suggestions?

Comment: The final HTTP status code is likely not known at this point ... in the _init_ phase you can hardly expect it to be already determined whether that requested URL actually leads to any content, or would for example result in a 404 ...

Comment: @CBroe so I need to hook it to another action? I've tried to hook it as a filter on http_response, but it doesn't seem to be called at each request and response...

Comment: Either find a hook that executes only after the response status code has been determined, or maybe look into a solution like this one, which relies on a basic PHP feature rather than WordPress, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120482/wordpress-run-an-action-after-page-sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_SERVER arrat doesn't contain current response status. 
So, try **http_response_code()** function instead.

Comment: I've already tried, but it shows always 200... i think that it shows the default response code, not the one generated by wordpress.

Comment: Is that different status shown in Chrome Network Inspector?

Comment: yes, if I access something that doesn't exist, in Chrome Network Insperctor it comes a 404 whereas with http_response_code() comes 200.

Comment: My bad, the function was working but the problem was that i called it too early, before the response status was known :D