# PHP avoid sleep while require

Tags: php, mysql, linux, iframe, sleep

I have two files say :
1. mail.php
2. Mail2.php

Code of mail.php goes like this :

```
<?
// code to send mail to stccircle@gmail.com 
sleep(20);
?>
```

Code of mail2.php goes like this

```
<?
// send another mail to stccircle@gmail.com 
?>
```

So, i want to execute both mail.php and mail2.php at once without sleep of mail.php affecting it.. i want to receive two mail at once..

I have tried :

```
require("mail.php");
require("mail2.php");
```

and

```
include("mail.php");
include("mail2.php");
```

Both codes wait till 20 seconds , i want the next email to be sent immediately after first one.. i want to open both link at once.

iframe fixes everything but cron job dosent support iframe.

**Sleep cannot be removed because it is main part of my code.**

Any solutions ?
Iframe is not supported by cron jobs..

**By the way, i want to run script through cron job ...**

Comment: *"corn job"* - You mean CRON job.

Comment: Yes i mean cron job :)

Comment: Can't you change the php code in your mail.php? But what about gmail. Won't they complain eventually?

Comment: No, i cant change sleep on my code.. its just a demo code, i have very long code pls help

Comment: can you edit mail.php? you could make `sleep` conditional, like: `define("SLEEP_TIME", 0);` in the cron-mail.php and in mail.php: `if (!defined("SLEEP_TIME") { define("SLEEP_TIME", 20); }` and   `sleep(SLEEP_TIME);`

Comment: _“Sleep cannot be removed because it is main part of my code”_ – that makes no sense to me at all. Either you deliberately want your script to sleep for a while – then you have to live with the “consequences”, that it delays execution of code that follows it within the same script instance – or you don’t want that, which means you would have to remove it.

Comment: Thanks for your answers :) I finally found my solution .. curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1000); This worked..

Answer (score 0):

Make two separate cron jobs instead, one that calls `mail.php` and the other calling `mail2.php`. Anohter option is making a http request to each site, but don't wait for the response. This question should help you with that.

[Send HTTP request from PHP without waiting for response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359926/send-http-request-from-php-without-waiting-for-response)

Comment: I tried get_headers(''); but it pauses for 20 seconds .. Help

Comment: Thanks for your answers :)
I finally found my solution ..

     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1000);
This worked..