# How to send post request to a url without waiting for result in zf2?

Tags: php, curl, asynchronous, zend-framework2

I want to send a post request to a url without waiting for the result. It is same as webhooks. If anyone knows how the webhooks in fb or payment gateways works then it would be very helpful.

Comment: You want to hit your own URL or some third party ?

Comment: Third party url.

Comment: Please refer to this post .

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359926/send-http-request-from-php-without-waiting-for-response

Comment: @MaazRehman have you used this one ? I am trying to use it but not getting appropriate result