# Running a shell script in the background from PHP

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

The scenario:

1. I have a PHP script (accessed via the web) which generates a shell script which needs to continue to run even after the request ends.
2. I need the output sent to a file on disk (i.e. "./script.sh > run.log")

Every approach I try seems to result in PHP still waiting for the shell script to finish executing. Approaches I've tried:

1. `nohup ./script.sh > run.log &`
2. `nohup ./script.sh > run.log 2>&1`
3. `nohup ./script.sh > run.log 2>&1 &`
4. `./script.sh &`
5. `./script.sh > run.log 2>&1`
6. `./script.sh > run.log &`

I think there's something really obvious I might be missing. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the shell script need to be run as the same user as your web server runs?  What about running a daemon of some sort to launch the shell script, and have your PHP script simply send a trigger to the daemon? Also, does your PHP script really need to *generate* the shell script? That seems very risky to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your number 5 approach is close but you need to combine it with 6 like this

```
shell_exec("/script.sh > run.log 2>&1 &");
```

Or redirect to /dev/null like this

```
shell_exec("/script.sh > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &")
```

---

***It appears that the PHP development server cannot fork off commands properly.*** Using a real web server like Apache or NGinx will resolve the issue.

Comment: I made that change and the PHP is still blocking until the shell script finishes executing. Do you think that's because I'm using PHP's built-in web server? Would switching to nginx/php-fpm fix it?

Comment: I installed nginx/php-fpm and that resolved the issue. **It appears that the PHP development server cannot fork off commands properly.**

Answer (score 2):

I think you could achieve this by starting a `screen` instance with the script:

```
screen -d -m 'bash ./script.sh > run.log'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried shell_exec ?

You might be interested in this post : [Is there a way to use shell_exec without waiting for the command to complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019867/is-there-a-way-to-use-shell-exec-without-waiting-for-the-command-to-complete)