# how to execute python script in PHP as a without waiting for completion?

Tags: php, exec

there is a python script

> StartDeploy.py

and i want to run this file from **PHP** without waiting for it's completion.

what can i do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use shell\_exec without waiting for the command to complete?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019867/is-there-a-way-to-use-shell-exec-without-waiting-for-the-command-to-complete)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
exec('python StartDeploy.py > /dev/null &');
```

It's for Linux.