# Asynchronous call to shell_exec() php

Tags: php, shell, asynchronous, command-line-interface

I am running a command using shell_exec()

Let's say I have 400 directories and I can not wait for the command to run completely.

Is there a way, I can get the output Asynchronous?

```
$output = shell_exec('ls');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

Comment: use pipes [popen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) or [proc_open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks a lot, proc_open() worked perfectly.

Comment: np glad to help, works great with web sockets too, something you might be interested in https://github.com/lcherone/phptty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$cmd = $command;

        $descriptorspec = array(
            0 => array("pipe", "r"),   // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
            1 => array("pipe", "w"),   // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
            2 => array("pipe", "w")    // stderr is a pipe that the child will write to
        );
        flush();
        $process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, realpath('./'), array());
        echo "<pre>";
        if (is_resource($process)) {
            while ($s = fgets($pipes[1])) {
                print $s;
                flush();
            }
        }
        echo "</pre>";
```

The Code above Worked perfectly for me, This is copied from another answer I can no longer find. If you put a `ping 127.0.0.1` in the `$command` it works exactly like it does in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: [Is there a way to use shell_exec without waiting for the command to complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019867/is-there-a-way-to-use-shell-exec-without-waiting-for-the-command-to-complete)

And instead of redirecting to /dev/null you could redirect to a tmp file that you read later.