# PHP: How to send ssh command and not wait until it is executed?

Tags: php, ssh

I have following function:

```
public function update($id){
   $data = $this->client_model->get_client_by_id($id);
   $sshport = $data['ssh_port'];
   $sshcommand = '/var/script/config.sh';
   $this->sshcommand($sshport, $sshcommand);
   $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Config has been sent');
   redirect(base_url('admin/edit/'.$id)) }
```

The sshcommand function looks like this:

```
private function sshcommand($port, $command) {
 $remotecommand = 'ssh -q root@localhost -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -p'.$port.' "'.$command.'" 2> /dev/null';
 $connection = ssh2_connect('controller.server.example.org', 22);
 ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($connection, 'root','/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub','/root/.ssh/id_rsa');
 ssh2_exec($connection, $remotecommand); }
```

My problem is that the first update function wait till `/var/script/config.sh` has finished.

But in some of my cases it takes very long, so I just want to sent the command and let it work in the background.

I tried to change it to `/var/script/config.sh | at now + 1 minute` but its the same result..

Any Ideas?

Comment: This is mostly related. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019867/is-there-a-way-to-use-shell-exec-without-waiting-for-the-command-to-complete

Comment: Thanks, but I tried to redirect stdout and stderr too with no success.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `&` with your command:

```
$sshcommand = '/var/script/config.sh &';
```

`bash` man page says:

> If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell executes the command in the background in a subshell. The shell does not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0.

Ensure shell you are using for **user** that is being used by ssh, supports that.

Alternatively you can try with `nohup`:

```
$sshcommand = 'nohup /var/script/config.sh';
```

This may also be shell dependant. `bash` works. Not sure about i.e. plain `sh` though.

Comment: In the first moment I though this is it, but than the script is not executed :(

Comment: Ensure  you use shell that supports that. Alternatively you can use `nohup`. I edited the answer.

Comment: thanks, it seems the problem is wget inside the config.sh..somehow... without & wget works and if I switch wget to curl the script works too. But sadly curl can't handle what I need, so I have to find out what exactly the problem with wget is.

Comment: Ok I ended up with `at now + 1 minute -f /var/data/setupplaylist.sh` which worked.

Comment: you should find the culprit, not mask it with workaround. Try to make your wget verbose and log its output somewhere. Then check why it fails